# WCF maxReceivedMessageSize cant set over 4215

Tags: c#, wcf, app-config

I want to set the maxReceivedMessageSize in the App.config of the WCF Client.

If the maxReceivedMessageSize equals or is smaller then  4215 it works fine. Though when setting it to 4216 or any value above it, the default value of 65536 is taken.

[image]

[image]

My Client Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IConexaApiServic" maxReceivedMessageSize="4216" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://svsr02.conexa.local/HelloService/ConexaApiService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IConexaApiServic"
                contract="ConexaApiService.IConexaApiService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IConexaApiService" />
        </client> 
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And The relavant Server Code

```
<basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpEndpoint_MPSAPIServic" maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpEndpoint_HelloService" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000">

  </binding>
   </basicHttpBinding>

 <service name="IIS_test123.HelloService">
        <endpoint address="ConexaApi" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpEndpoint_HelloService" contract="IIS_test123.IHelloService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/API/ConexaApiService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you check your IIS Manager settings if you are running on an IIS?

Comment: Why do you say that "it works fine" with a value of 4215 whereas your first screenshot shows an exception?

Comment: @PatriceGahide He means that setting the value works. As you can see in the first screenshot, the value mentioned in the exception text is 4215, whereas it is 65536 in the second.

Comment: I noticed that the addresses in the client and service configs don't match, specifically the service config specifies a port (8733) and the client doesn't.   Perhaps this is leading to some weird interplay with default endpoints and bindings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be explainned. If you look at your exceptions:

- System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException is an exception thrown from client side. It has the maxReceivedMessageSize from the client side. Everything is fine.
- FaultException: this exception is a SOAP fault that propagate the exceptions from the service to the client application. ( http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/799258/WCF-Exception-FaultException-FaultContract). So this exception is actually coming from the service side! The maxReceivedMessageSize is the default value, and does not correspond to the  maxReceivedMessageSize in your server configuration.
  The address you are connecting to in your client is the service address, not configured maxReceivedMessageSize, and  not the endpoint address ConexaApi which is configure with maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000". That' s why you are getting the default 65536.

And 4215 must be the size of your message if you consider that the exception does not raise if you increase it.